# How innodb tables are locked when ON INSERT trigger is processed?

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, innodb, table-locking

I have two innodb tables:

**articles**

```
id     | title    | sum_votes
------------------------------
1      | art 1    | 5
2      | art 2    | 8
3      | art 3    | 35
```

**votes**

```
id     | article_id    | vote
------------------------------
1      | 1             | 1
2      | 1             | 2
3      | 1             | 2
4      | 2             | 10
5      | 2             | -2
6      | 3             | 10
7      | 3             | 15
8      | 3             | 12
9      | 3             | -2
```

When a new record is inserted into the `votes` table, I want to update the `sum_votes` field in `articles` table by calculating the sum of all votes.

## The question

Which way is more efficient, if the SUM() calculation itself is a very heavy one (`votes` table has 700K records).

**1. Creating a trigger**

```
CREATE TRIGGER `views_on_insert`
AFTER INSERT
ON `votes`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   UPDATE `articles` SET
       sum_votes = (
           SELECT SUM(`vote`)
           FROM `votes`
           WHERE `id` = NEW.article_id
       )
    WHERE `id` = NEW.article_id;
END;
```

**2. Using two queries in my application**

```
SELECT SUM(`vote`) FROM `votes` WHERE `article_id` = 1;
UPDATE `articles` 
   SET sum_votes = <1st_query_result> 
 WHERE `id` = 1;
```

1st way seems cleaner, but **will the table be locked the whole time the SELECT query runs?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

About the concurrency problems, you have an *'easy'* way to prevent any concurrency problems in the 2nd method, inside your transaction perform a select on the articles line (the `For update` is now implicit). Any concurrent insert on the same article will not be able to obtain this same lock and will wait for you.

With the new default isolation levels, without even using serialization level in the transaction you wouldn't see any concurrent insert on the vote table until the end of your transaction. So your SUM should stay coherent **or looks like coherent**. But if a concurrent transaction insert a vote on same article and commit before you (and this 2nd one does not see your insert), the last transaction to commit will overwrite the counter and you'll loose  1 vote. *So perform a row lock on article by using a select before* (and do your work in a transaction, of course). It's easy to test, open 2 interactive sessions on MySQL and start transactions with BEGIN.

If you use the trigger you are in a transaction by default. But I think you should perform as well the select on the article table to make an implicit row lock for concurrent triggers running (harder to test).

- Do not forget delete triggers.
- Do not forget update triggers.
- If you do not use triggers and stay
  in code, be careful every
  insert/delete/update query on vote
  should perform a row lock on the
  corresponding article before in the
  transaction. It's not very hard to
  forget one.

Last point: make harder transactions, before starting the transaction use:

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE;
```

This way you do not need row locks on articles, MySQL will detect that a potential write on the same row occurs and will block the others transaction until you finish. *But do not use something you have computed from a previous request*. The update query will be waiting for a lock release on articles, when the lock is released by the 1st transaction `COMMIT` the computing of `SUM` should be done again to count. So the update query should contain the `SUM` or make an addition.

```
update articles set nb_votes=(SELECT count(*) from vote) where id=2;
```

And here you'll see that MySQL is smart, a deadlock is detected if 2 transactions are trying to do this while insert has been done in a concurrent time. In serialization levels I haven't found a way to obtain a wrong value with :

```
   SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE;
   BEGIN;
       insert into vote (...
       update articles set nb_votes=(
         SELECT count(*) from vote where article_id=xx
       ) where id=XX;
    COMMIT;
```

But be ready to handle breaking transaction that you must redo.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

[PHP: Star rating system concept?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4519779/php-star-rating-system-concept/4519969#4519969)

**EDIT:** changed schema to allow a user to vote for the same image many times:

```
drop table if exists image;
create table image
(
image_id int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key,
caption varchar(255) not null,
num_votes int unsigned not null default 0,
total_score int unsigned not null default 0,
rating decimal(8,2) not null default 0
)
engine = innodb;

drop table if exists image_vote;
create table image_vote
(
vote_id int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key,
image_id int unsigned not null,
user_id int unsigned not null,
score tinyint unsigned not null default 0,
key (image_id, user_id)
)
engine=innodb;

delimiter #

create trigger image_vote_after_ins_trig after insert on image_vote
for each row
begin
 update image set 
    num_votes = num_votes + 1,
    total_score = total_score + new.score,
    rating = total_score / num_votes  
 where 
    image_id = new.image_id;
end#

delimiter ;

insert into image (caption) values ('image 1'),('image 2'), ('image 3');

insert into image_vote (image_id, user_id, score) values
(1,1,5),(1,2,4),(1,3,3),(1,4,2),(1,5,1),(1,5,2),(1,5,3),
(2,1,2),(2,2,1),(2,3,4),(2,3,2),
(3,1,4),(3,5,2);

select * from image;
select * from image_vote;
```

Comment: In given example there were no need to calculate SUM() every time, because there were only one vote per records. they just did '+1' on each insert. I have a different situation.

Comment: you can change the constraint so a user can vote many times on the same image - that's not a problem. ( total_score = total_score + new.score...)

Comment: @silver - the sum is the sum total of all the scores, votes is the sum total of all the votes ! the rating is then calculated from those values !

Comment: @silver, why would you want that a user can vote more then once? in this way your system is going to be corrupt and the rank isn't accurate?

Comment: @Tricker, vote weight is different, depending on user's rank.

Comment: @silver - omg, you've been spoon fed the solution - go away and play with it... adding a weighting to whatever value you SCORE is trivial -it's just part of the trigger !!

Comment: @silver "When a new record is inserted into the votes table, I want to update the sum_votes field in articles table by calculating the sum of all votes." no you dont. YOU WANT TO INCREMENTALLY SUM THE SCORES !!!

Comment: @f00, sorry, but I did not ask to code for me, I just wanted to know how tables are locked and witch of my solutions will be better at performance. Please read the question again.

Comment: @silver "When a new record is inserted into the votes table, I want to update the sum_votes field in articles table by calculating the sum of all votes." - idiotic in the extreme.